# Reference to static field as parameter value in Struts2

Tags: struts2

Is it possible to have a result as follows:

```
        <result name="defaultLocaleLoginScreen" type="httpheader">
            <param name="status">301</param>
            <param name="headers.Location">${@zzz.yyy.xxx.MyClass@MyValue}</param>
    </result>
```

Where MyValue is a static field of the class MyClass. I haven't been able to get that to work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after all it works just fine, I don't know what I was doing wrong. I need something more complicate than just a static field, I needed to execute a static method, and then a getter from the returned object. The final solution was:

```
<param name="headers.Location">${@zzz.yyy.xxx.Myclass@getInstance().getValue()}</param>
```